# How do I create drag and drop upload for angular2

Tags: node.js, file-upload, angular, upload

I've seen tons of partial information but nothing that explains the full process of how to add a drag and drop upload to angular2. I've looked at **ng2-file-upload** and **angular2-file-drop** and **file-droppa**. They are all very easy to get the front end working, but with no explanation on the backend its been impossible to fully implement.

My latest attempt has been with **file-droppa**. I really like the look and feel of this one. (https://github.com/ptkach/fileDroppa)

So I have it deployed in so much as I can drag an image into the drop zone, see the thumbnail show up and click the **Upload All Files** button. What I'm missing is the magic required to get any information about the file in the backend of my application to be able to actually upload it and do anything with it.

I'm using NodeJS on the backend. The method for /upload gets called, but nothing is being passed into it.

Anyone know how to make this work?

**assets.component.ts**

```
import FileDroppa from 'file-droppa/components/Directives/FileDroppa';
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'pc-assets',
  templateUrl: 'assets.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['assets.component.css'],
  directives: [FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTIVES, NgClass, NgStyle, CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, FileDroppa]   
})

export class AssetsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() asset:Asset;
  @Input() uploads: Upload[];

  constructor(private assetService: AssetService,
              private errorService: ErrorService,
              private http: Http,
              private formBuilder:FormBuilder,
              private uploadFileService: UploadFileService) { }

  assets: Asset[] = [];
  selectedAsset: Asset;
  assetFilesToUpload: Array<File>;
  assetUploaded = false;
  assetUploadFile: any;
  assetUploadObject: any;
  uploadFile: any;

  assetFileChangeEvent(fileInput: any){
    this.assetFilesToUpload = <Array<File>> fileInput.target.files;
  }

  fileUploaded(success, response, file){
    success && console.log("uploaded - awesome", response, file);
    success || console.log("not uploaded - very bad", response, file);
  }
}
```

**assets.component.html**

```
  <fileDroppa
    [url]="'http://localhost:3000/upload'"
    [showFilesList]="true"
    (fileUploaded)="fileUploaded($event)"
  >
    <!--<h1>-->

    <!--You can pass anything you want here-->
    <!--You can set you own file list here-->
    <!--</h1>-->
  </fileDroppa>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngx-file-drop package of node for implement drag and drop functionality :

hear is link for that  :   [ngx-file-drop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-file-drop)

documentation is very easy with example.